# Multiple WHERE using QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

When using the following only the last `where` is added to my query;

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select(array('qi'))
    ->from('Table:Qi', 'qi')
    ->where("qi.content = " . $content->getId())
    ->where("qi.queue = " . $child->getQueue()->getId());
```

I had to do this to make it take notice of both

```
$qb->select(array('qi'))
    ->from('Table:Qi', 'qi')
    ->where("qi.content = " . $content->getId() . 
                 " AND qi.queue = " . $child->getQueue()->getId());
```

This does not seem right? How can I use the first approach with multiple `where` calls?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `->andWhere` like this:

```
->where("qi.content = " . $content->getId())
->andWhere("qi.queue = " . $child->getQueue()->getId());
```

Comment: you actually dont **need** to use `->where` before `andWhere`. You can alway use `->andWhere();`